# SIrange with a preunit

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to use the `siunitx` package to typeset currency ranges (e.g. $100 to $300 million). A single value can be typeset as

```
\SI{100}[$]{billion}
```

which correctly gives

> $100 billion

Trying

```
\SIrange{100}{300}[\$]{million}
```

on the other hand, gives

> 100 [ to 300 [$]million

What is the most appropriate way to typeset these? Should I just add the preunit (`\$`) to each of numbers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I don't think it's currently possible to pass a pre-unit item to `\SIrange`. If you decide to go the route mentioned in the final sentence, you'll also need to set the option `parse-numbers=false`, i.e., write `\SIrange[parse-numbers=false]{\$100}{\$300}{million}`. However, the resulting output -- "$100 million to $300 million" looks turgid. I'm pretty sure nobody will become confused if you write "$100 to $300 million".

Comment: Thank you. I feel that this might be the closest to an answer for this question. If you add it as such, I will accept it.

Comment: Done. I've added a note about the type of `$` possibly needing to be flagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible to pass a pre-unit item to `\SIrange`. If you decide to go the route mentioned in the final sentence, you'll also need to set the option `parse-numbers=false`, i.e., write

```
\SIrange[parse-numbers=false]{\$100}{\$300}{million}.
```

However, the resulting output -- "$100 million to $300 million" is not very idiomatic (at least not for English). I'm pretty sure nobody will be confused if you wrote out the phrase using words, i.e.,

```
$100 to $300 million
```

or, better still (IMNSHO),

```
100 to 300 million dollars
```

Of course, if there's any uncertainty as to *which* country's currency unit -- United States, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Hong Kong, Singapore, ..., Zimbabwe [!] -- is being referred to, do make sure to quash that potential ambiguity.